# Remove a MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event listener if no user interaction occurs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm new to AS3 and need help figuring out how to remove my `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` listener if no user interaction occurs.

I have built an animation that does the following:
A solid line and some text appear on top of an image. After this finishes a mouse event is enabled that allows the user to move the line up and down. When the user stops interacting with the line, the line disappears and the final screen of the animation appears.

In the event that the user does not interact with the animation at all (the line never moves), I need to incorporate some way to remove the event listener, then have the final screen of the animation appear. I think adding a `TimerEvent` is the correct approach for doing what I want, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it. This also may not be the best or correct method. In that case, does anyone have suggestions as to what should be done?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import com.greensock.*;

//objects on the stage
line_mc.y=250;
raisingTxt.alpha=0;
arrow_mc.alpha=0;
final_mc.alpha=0;
logo_mc.alpha=1 ;


//move line mc to y:125
TweenLite.to(line_mc, 1, {y:125});
TweenLite.to(raisingTxt, .5, {alpha:1, delay:1.2});
TweenLite.to(arrow_mc, .5, {alpha:1, delay:1.2, onComplete:followMouse});


//calls MouseEvent onComplete of tween
function followMouse() {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveIt);
}

function moveIt(e:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(line_mc, 0.5, {y:this.mouseY});
    TweenLite.to([raisingTxt,arrow_mc], 0.5, {alpha:0, onComplete:finalScreen} );
}

//calls final screen onComplete of MouseEvent
function finalScreen() {
    TweenLite.to(line_mc, 0.5, {alpha:0} );
    TweenLite.to(final_mc, 0.5, {alpha:1} );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `setTimeout()` ? Or perhaps a better option would be to use a Timer object. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: you never remove your mouse move listener and you create too many tweenlite instances anyway. This code is too CPU expensive and will generate memory leaks.

Comment: @BotMaster Why would it generate memory leaks?

Comment: each time you move the mouse you'll generate either 4 tweenlite instances or an error.

Comment: @BotMaster is incorrect. These are static functions it does not create any tweenlite instances, and the cpu usage is negligible. You are definitely going to want to use a timer for this, I can mock something up and submit an answer.

Comment: @C.Parcell I've looked into setTimeout() and can get it to work independently of my code, but am not sure how to incorporate it, although it sounds like a timer is the best option.

Comment: @BennettYeates If you could mock something up with a timer I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the built in `Timer` class. I like it a bit more than the setTimeout `function` because it's simpler to manage.

First create a class wide variable (assuming you are doing this in the Flash IDE, just create it near the top)

```
var timeout:Timer;
```

Then in your `followMouse()`:

```
private function followMouse():void {
    timeout = new Timer( 3000, 1 );
    timeout.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeMouseListener );
    timeout.start();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveIt);
}
```

Last create the `removeMouseListener()`:

```
private function removeMouseListener( e:Event=null ):void {
    timeout.removeEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeMouseListener );
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveIt);
}
```

If you want to keep resetting the timer every time the mouse moves, you can add these two lines to your `moveIt()`:

```
timeout.reset();
timeout.start();
```

I made the `removeMouseListener()` have an optional parameter so you can call it any time regardless of the timer.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your instructions are very clear and my animation now works exactly the way I need it to.

Comment: @C.Parcell Done. Sorry about that. I'm new to this site and didn't realize that needed to be done. Thanks for your help.